# Async callback function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, callback

I am trying to re-use a modal for when different types of users get created as the logic is quite similar. The modal accepts a callback function which handles calling the action to create a user.

Have changed a lot of the types to use any while trying to debug as I thought improper types might have something to do with it so don't pay to much attention to the types.

Here I am expecting a addUserCallback function inside the interface and prop destructuring

```
    interface AddUserModalProps {
    closeModal: () => void
    isLineOfContact: boolean
    addUserCallback: any
    isLoading: boolean
    errors?: any
}

const AddUserModal: React.FC<AddUserModalProps> = ({
    closeModal,
    isLineOfContact,
    isLoading,
    errors = null,
    addUserCallback,
}) => {
```

Here is how I am using that function

```
const handleAddUser = async () => {
    if (!isFormValidated()) {
        return
    }

    const user: any = {
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        country_id: countryId,
    }

    if (isLineOfContact) {
        user[position] = position
    }
    
    const success = addUserCallback(user)
    
    if(success) {
        closeModal()
    }
}
```

Here is the function I am parsing in as the addUserCallback

```
    const handleAddLineOfContact = (user: any) => async () => {
        const success: any = await addLineOfContacts(organization.id, selectedOrganizationInformation.id, user)
   
        return success
    }
```

And finally this is the action that gets called inside handleAddLineOfContact

```
export const addLineOfContacts =
(
    organizaitonId: number,
    clientId: number,
    payload: CreateLineOfContactInterface,
) =>
    async (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(setLineOfContactLoading())

        const res = await axios.post(
            `${apiUrl}/v1/partners/${organizaitonId}/clients/${clientId}/contact-lines`,
            payload,
        )
        if (res.status !== 201) {
            // TODO handle error display
            return false
        }

        dispatch({
            type: LineOfContactActionType.ADD_LINE_OF_CONTACT,
            payload: res.data.data,
        })

        return true
    }
```

The simple problem is that it seems handleAddLineOfContact never runs. Also if I console log right before it is called it gets printed but if I console log after it does not.

Comment: Not sure if this is all your problems, but `const success = addUserCallback(user)`, you will want an `await` here -> `const success = await addUserCallback(user)`

Comment: `addUserCallback: any` - stop there and declare a proper type. What should the function take as an argument and what should it return? Same for `const success: any` - what is that value, really? Tell the compiler what you expect, and have it validate that for you. If you think about these a bit, you'll also find the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Bergi the any types are not the problem and I added them while trying to debug because it was not working in the first place and I thought it might be related. If I specify the addUserCallback as :(user: UserInterface) => boolean and do nothing but return a boolean from the function I parse in it still does not work.

Comment: @Keith It's not the problem I have tried it both ways. According to WebStorm the await was not needed which I thought sounded odd and wanted to try it but either way it does not work.

Comment: Is it on purpose that `handleAddLineOfContact` returns a function? Maybe there's one arrow function too many. It looks like you're only calling it once, by passing the user object.

Comment: @timotgl I am returning of the addLineOfContacts which I invoke which will be either true or false so how is it returning a function? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: `According to WebStorm the await was not needed`,  because you have put -> `addUserCallback: any`  Your not saying it's a Promise, so webstorm will give you that error.   `addUserCallback:Promise<any>` at least, if your expecting a Promise,.    Also like mentioned your double function won't help -> `(user: any) => async () => {`   try -> `async (user) => {.....`  or `const success = await addUserCallback(user)()` but that justs seem odd.

Comment: @timotgl You guy and keith are indeed right. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!